# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Cannot click on element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to click on the dropdown menu in my web application and then click on the sub items which are in  DIV. Below is the code which I am trying to execute.

```
WebElement mnuElement;
WebElement submnuElement;

mnuElement = driver.findElement(By.id("CollectorsTab"));
//  Thread.sleep(3000);

submnuElement = driver.findElement(By.id("IdentityCollectorsTab"));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
// Move cursor to the Main Menu Element
builder.moveToElement(mnuElement).perform();
// Pause 2 Seconds for submenu to be displayed
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2); //Pause 2 seconds
// Clicking on the Hidden submnuElement
submnuElement.click();
```

I have read in some of the questions that of trying more wait which also I have tried but I am getting all the time below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Cannot click on element
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
System info: host: 'UKPC31732', ip: '172.31.1.202', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=11, se:ieOptions={nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:1486/, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false}, browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=WINDOWS, setWindowRect=true, platform=WINDOWS}]
Session ID: e6579c86-fd88-4ce0-8820-1d4c644ba7ee
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:185)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
    at FlowIAM.main(FlowIAM.java:67)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to click on submenu

```
WebElement mnuElement;
WebElement submnuElement;

mnuElement = driver.findElement(By.id("CollectorsTab"));
submnuElement = driver.findElement(By.id("IdentityCollectorsTab"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(mnuElement).clickAndHold(submnuElement).click().build().perform();
```

Sometime we need to click and hold and then have to click on submenu. Hope this code help

Comment: Thanks This also works! this is similar which i was just trying.